# Weird behavior of sudo

Tags: linux, authentication, sudo, su

I use putty to log in to a remote LINUX machine. (Ubuntu 10)

When I log in I have to authenticate myself, that goes on pretty smooth.

Whenever I try to use `sudo` or `su` though, I experience Authentication failures. I am entering the same password I entered when logging in.

I can't read the `sudoers` file too.

Had no problems with sudo till a week back, any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: maybe the root password has been changed

Comment: No, it has not.

Comment: You can't read the sudoers file without root access and you cannot get root access without sudo working.  If `su` and then root password is not working (assuming you enabled root), then the root password is not what you believe it is.  If you can no longer sudo, then you are no longer in the sudoers file.  Either this, or something has changed in pam.  If you administer this server, and you haven't made changes to these things, then someone else has.  It is time to boot into single user mode and see what is happening.

Comment: is your user a sudoer? also have you tried to use sudo with physical access?

Comment: @Sadly, I am not the administrator and there may have changes to PAM. I will check if thats the case with my administrator